# Create Value in final column of dataframe based on multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe that looks like this (but with a lot more variables/columns)

```
set.seed(5)
id<-seq(5)*floor(runif(5,min=1000, max=10000))
vals1<-c("Y","N","N","N","N")
vals2<-c("N","N","N","N","N")
vals3<-c("N","N","N","Y","N")
df<-data.frame(id,vals1,vals2,vals3)
```

I'd like to create a final column in the frame such that it generates a final flag with the following logic:  If there is any value of 'Y' for any id the final flag is 'Y', otherwise it would be a 'N'. So, for this dataframe the 1st and 4th ids (2801, 14236) has a 'Y' in the final column and the rest have an 'n' for the final column. I tried a few approaches like apply and if...else to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize by assigning "N" to every row. In next step, for the rows with "Y" (check using `apply`), assign "Y"

```
df$final = "N"
df$final[apply(df, 1, function(a) "Y" %in% a)] = "Y"
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A solution for your letter encoding below.

```
set.seed(5)
id <- seq(5) * floor(runif(5, min=1000, max=10000))
vals1 <- c("Y","N","N","N","N")
vals2 <- c("N","N","N","N","N")
vals3 <- c("N","N","N","Y","N")

df <- data.frame(id, vals1, vals2, vals3)

# If you really want to use the letter encoding, my solution works as below
df$Final <- apply(df[,2:4], MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) {any(x == 'Y')})
```

However, I think you should use a boolean (TRUE/FALSE) for this.

Works well in combination with `apply` and `any`

```
set.seed(5)
id <- seq(5) * floor(runif(5, min=1000, max=10000))
vals1 <- c("Y","N","N","N","N")
vals2 <- c("N","N","N","N","N")
vals3 <- c("N","N","N","Y","N")

df <- data.frame(id, vals1, vals2, vals3)

# Convert your labels into booleans:
df[,2:4] <- df[,2:4] == 'Y'

# Then summarise across rows
df$Final <- apply(df[,2:4], MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) {any(x)})
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat similar to the @d.b answer:

```
df$final <- apply(df, 1, function(x) c("N","Y")[any(x == "Y")+1])
```